# Closed form for this summation

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

How do we prove that $$S=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n} \sin n=\dfrac{e\sin 1}{1+e^2-2e\cos 1}\approx0.419$$

We can write the sum as $$S=\Im \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{(i-1)n}$$

I do not know what to do next. Answers or hints appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
S
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(-1+i)}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{-1+i}}{1-e^{-1+i}}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{-1+i}}{1-e^{-1+i}}\frac{1-e^{-1-i}}{1-e^{-1-i}}\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{-1+i}-e^{-2}}{1-2e^{-1}\cos(1)+e^{-2}}\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}\sin(1)}{1-2e^{-1}\cos(1)+e^{-2}}\\
&=\frac{e\sin(1)}{e^2-2e\cos(1)+1}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Use the formula for geometric series, and then compute its imaginary part.

Comment: Is it applicable even in complex numbers?

Comment: @Pkwssis: as long as the absolute value of the ratio is less than $1$, it applies.

Comment: @robjohn Got it..Thanks!